# Manage locale with Symfony3 LocaleSubscriber

Tags: php, symfony

I've some troubles in using locale parameter with Symfony 3. I've tried a lot of things that I've found on Stack, but nothing seems to work.

I've followed the official documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html

## LocaleSubscriber.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->get('_locale')) {
            $request->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            $request->set('_locale', $this->defaultLocale);
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered after the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

## config.yml

```
framework:
#esi: ~
translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

## service.yml

```
AppBundle\EventSubscriber\LocaleSubscriber:
    arguments: ['%kernel.default_locale%']
    tags: [kernel.event_subscriber]
```

## AdminController

```
namespace AdminBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function homeAction(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump($request->getLocale());
        var_dump($request->get('_locale'));
        return $this->render('AdminBundle:home:home.html.twig');
    }
}
```

## HTML Links :

```
<li><a href="{{-path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale' : 'fr'}))-}}">FR</a></li>
<li><a href="{{-path(app.request.get('_route'), app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale' : 'en'}))-}}">EN</a></li>
```

**Problem** : When I try to switch of language, the parameter _locale is changed but the text don't switch language. "testfr" must be "testen" according to my messages.en.yml.

**My var_dump when I click on the "FR" link :** string(2) "fr" string(2) "fr"

**My var_dump when I click on the "EN" link :** string(2) "fr" string(2) "en"
I guess it is not normal..

If someone can help me, that would be nice and can remove a headache.

Thanks

Edit : The translator takes the "locale" parameter, which doesn't change when I click on one of theses links. I'm still investigating.

Comment: For me the best way is to use "jms/i18n-routing-bundle" . This bundle is very simple and it gives you all you nned fro out of the box. Just try.

Comment: I'll but I'm still curious why it didn't work like that

Comment: "Locale" parameter in config.yml = "fr" currently, and didn't change thanks to the LocaleSubscriber. But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found the problem :

```
   if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
        return;
    }
```

Just comment this part of the code, and all is fine now.